# how to display images from a selected folder in the form of a slideshow

Tags: android

I am using the following code to pick a folder from the SDCard.

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

After selecting the folder, I return the path of the folder and display it in a text view currently. 
What I want to do is, I want to display all images in the selected folder in the form of a slide show. How do I go about in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
1. convert images in the Bitmap.
   Bitmap bm =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String pathName);
```

Decode a file path into a bitmap.BitmapFactory

```
2. Using ImageView set that Bitmap in ImageView. 
   ImageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm);
```

Sets a Bitmap as the content of this ImageView.

```
3. For slide show just after some delay (use timer) after change the bitmap of ImageView.
```

**We are appreciate If you are do by yourself. Without finding any code.**

EDIT: Here **Mihai Fonoage's Blog** [Displaying Images from SD Card In Android - Part 2](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/11/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html)  It display images from sdcard in Gridview. You can modified it and display Images one-by-one as a slideshow.

Comment: Now, I'm am able to display a single image by specifying the full path of the image in "pathname". What I want is to give the path to the folder containing images and that all of the images in that folder should be displayed one after the other. If I give the path to the folder in BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String pathname), I am not able to display images.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is cycle through the images one by one, there are numerous options. You could for example simply use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) (or preferably a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) if you're writing production code) with a fixed interval or have a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) repeatedly post itself with a certain delay. With each 'tick' you can then simply set the next image.

If you're after something a little more fancy, it may be worth looking at implementing an ImageSwitcher, which provides the ability to also show thumbs of upcoming/previous images. Code examples are wide spread, e.g. [here](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-3-more-views) (scroll down a bit).